# Limits on phase speed for a growing instability?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, relativity, stability

When analyzing the Rayleigh-Taylor instability relativistically, a growing instability only occurs for $ \frac {\omega^2} {k^2 c^2} \ll 1 $. Why must the phase speed of the instability be sufficiently slow from a physical standpoint?

Comment: What density gradients do you envision generating perturbations moving near the speed of light?  Further, if the phase speed of a Rayleigh-Taylor instability generated relativistic flows, one would need to worry about other effects not directly related to this instability (e.g., ionization effects).  That is, I am saying you should check to see if the low phase speed is a requirement or an assumption.

Comment: One could perform a linear stability analysis at the interface of two fluids with each at constant density and any positive Atwood number. Such a relativistic hydrodynamic RTI is investigated in a paper entitled "The Rayleigh—Taylor instability in astrophysical fluids" by Allen & Hughes (1984). In that paper, for example, a requirement in their dispersion relation for a purely growing instability to be permitted is a phase speed much smaller than c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what the perturbation wavenumber $k$ and the growth rate parameter $\omega$ mean in the real, physical world.

[image: The Rayleigh-Taylor instability]

$k$ is a measure of the size of the growing perturbation at the boundary of the two fluids; $\omega$ is a measure of the speed at which it grows.  Thus, we expect information about the newly created perturbation to travel outward at a velocity of order $\omega/k$.  Since information cannot move faster than light, an approximate limit on the phase velocity, $\omega/k < c$, becomes obvious.

Must $\omega/k$ be *much* less than $c$ rather than merely *less than* $c$?  First of all, it's worth noting that the upper bound on the phase velocity actually isn't all that far from $c$.  It looks like you're getting the idea that $\omega^2/k^2 c^2 \ll 1$ from section 4.1 of the Allen and Hughes paper you mentioned in the comments.  The only justification they provide is their equation 27, but they don't provide the actual solutions to the equation; in fact, the positive root is located at $\omega^2/k^2 c^2 = \frac{1}{12}(7+\sqrt{97}) \approx 1.40$, indicating that the maximum possible phase velocity is about 1.18$c$.  Intuitively, this seems reasonable; the perturbation takes more than just one time constant to reach depth $z$, so it makes sense that the phase velocity can be a little bit larger than $c$.

Comment: Well we expect information to travel outward at $\partial \omega / \partial \vec{k}$ which could be finite (and $\ll c$) even if $\omega / k$ is infinite. It is not quite obvious that your approximate limit above necessarily holds generally for a perturbation.

Comment: Yes, that is the particular section and equation which appeared unintuitive and raised this question. In general, why is there a critical wavenumber for RTI (i.e. lower limit) and maximum phase speed (i.e. upper limit) for instabilities? This is perhaps the more general underlying question here.

Comment: @Mathews24 You're technically right, and of course this is an important distinction for ordinary propagating waves.  But the group velocity and phase velocity are normally of the same order of magnitude, and the Rayleigh-Taylor instability is not one of the exceptions.  Intuitive justification: the perturbation starts out at some finite size and takes a few time constants $1/\omega$ to grow exponentially to a size of a few times $1/k$; therefore, information has propagated at a speed of somewhere around $\omega/k$.

Comment: To make that more mathematically rigorous, the dispersion relation of the incompressible Rayleigh-Taylor instability is $\omega^2 = gk\eta$ where $\eta$ is the Atwood number.  Thus $\omega/k = g\eta / \omega$ and $d\omega / dk = g\eta / 2\omega$, i.e. the group velocity is exactly half the phase velocity.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth clarifying: the only aspect of the paper by Allen & Hughes that includes relativistic effects was the equation of state: $ \rho =\rho_0 + 3pc^2$ (1). This is valid when analyzing hot fluids without bulk flows. They appear to simply plug (1) into classical non-relativistic hydrodynamic equations for continuity, momentum, and energy. Reading through Landau & Lifshitz (1963) and Weinberg (1972), I can easily recover (1) and (2), but not (3) - (4). In a fully relativistic analysis, I would suspect the hard upper bound of the perturbation phase velocity to be c instead of 1.18c.